# Creating New Multidimensional Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to obtain this kind of array:

```
[array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ -9.19361118e-02,  -5.62946325e-18,  -9.95764908e-01]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([  9.19361118e-02,   5.62946325e-18,   9.95764908e-01])]
[array([ -4.02455846e-16,  -2.46433132e-32,  -1.00000000e+00]), array([  4.02455846e-16,   2.46433132e-32,   1.00000000e+00]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])]
[array([ -1.32548132e-01,  -8.11623230e-18,   5.20417043e-17]), array([  6.07243954e-01,   3.71829682e-17,  -4.38273008e-02]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ -4.74695821e-01,  -2.90667359e-17,   4.38273008e-02])]
[array([  9.89550969e-01,  -1.21185043e-16,  -1.44183494e-01]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ -9.89550969e-01,   1.21185043e-16,   1.44183494e-01]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])]
[array([ -6.17327484e-02,   7.56008127e-18,   4.86015631e-01]), array([  1.32548132e-01,  -1.62324646e-17,  -0.00000000e+00]), array([ -7.08153840e-02,   8.67238333e-18,  -4.86015631e-01]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])]
[array([  5.84181997e-17,  -9.58615055e-01,  -0.00000000e+00]), array([  2.36516717e-18,   6.64023184e+00,   0.00000000e+00]), array([ -6.07833668e-17,  -4.96333856e-01,   0.00000000e+00]), array([ 0.        , -5.18528293,  0.        ])]
```

Therefore I createa a new array 6 by 4 by 3.

```
ves = np.zeros((6,5), dtype=object)
```

I started filling up elements:

```
ves[0][0] = np.array([0,0,-1])
ves[0][1] = np.array([0,0,1])
ves[0][2] = np.array([0,0,0])
ves[0][3] = np.array([0,0,0])

ves[1][0] = np.array([0,0,0])
ves[1][1] = np.array([0,0,0])
ves[1][2] = np.array([0,0,0])
ves[1][3] = np.array([0,0,0])
```

And noticed that I am not getting expected results.

```
[ -1.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00  -6.12323400e-17]
[  1.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   6.12323400e-17]
[ 0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.]
....
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your expected result, remove last index:

```
ves = np.zeros((6,5), dtype=object)

ves[0][0] = np.array([0,0,-1])
```

and so on...

Comment: It still is not the same.